# how to convert html template in to squarespace theme?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I have a simple HTML template. I would like to convert it into a `squarespace` theme, I couldn't find any help. Please guide me to convert this.

Comment: http://developers.squarespace.com/get-started if you can't follow this then maybe you shouldn't create a template as it might be really bad for the user.

Comment: but I want to understand the structure how to convert single html page to squarespace page?

Comment: https://developers.squarespace.com/initial-setup/ here's another page from squarespace. I don't think anyone here is willing to rewrite the guide for you to understand lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://base-template.squarespace.com/
Follow above mentioned link it is guiding to create template from scratch.